# MySQL Trigger: delete indirectly associated entries

Tags: mysql, sqlite, triggers

1 author can have many books / 1 book can have many authors

[image]

When an **author is deleted**, how can I trigger MySQL (SQLite) to delete **books** whose author is only uniquely the one being deleted on **authors**, so it won't have books without authors associated to it?

Example:

```
BOOK1: John & Paul
BOOK2: John
BOOK3: Lucy
BOOK4: John & Lucy
```

if I delete john from authors then the trigger would delete BOOK2 only.

authors_books' both foreign keys: `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this simple trigger. Works perfectly:

```
PRAGMA primary_keys = ON;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TRIGGER DEL_BOOKS BEFORE DELETE ON authors_books
WHEN

 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM authors_books WHERE
  fk_book_id = OLD.fk_book_id AND fk_author_id != OLD.fk_author_id) = 0 

BEGIN

  DELETE FROM books WHERE books.book_id = OLD.fk_book_id;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need pure `trigger` solution then consider the following

```
mysql> create table authors (author_id int , name varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> create table books (book_id int, title varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> create table authors_books (fk_author_id int,fk_book_id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into authors values (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into books values (1,'book1'),(2,'book2'),(3,'book3'),(4,'book4');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into authors_books values (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(1,3),(1,4),(3,4);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Lets write the trigger now

```
delimiter //
create trigger auth_delete after delete on authors
for each row
begin
 delete b from books b 
 join authors_books ab on ab.fk_book_id = b.book_id 
 where ab.fk_author_id = old.author_id 
 and not exists (
   select 1 from authors_books ab1 
   where b.book_id = ab1.fk_book_id 
   and ab1.fk_author_id <> ab.fk_author_id
  );

  delete from authors_books where fk_author_id = old.author_id ;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

In the above code I am also deleting the row `authors_books` for the author who is getting deleted.

**Test ::**

```
mysql> delete from authors where author_id = 1 ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from authors_books ;
+--------------+------------+
| fk_author_id | fk_book_id |
+--------------+------------+
|            2 |          1 |
|            3 |          2 |
|            3 |          4 |
+--------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from books ;
+---------+-------+
| book_id | title |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | book1 |
|       2 | book2 |
|       4 | book4 |
+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Neat code! Thanks. Is there a better way to design this scenario so I don't have to use triggers? (`ON DELETE CASCADE` instead)

Comment: well the issue is the relation is `one-to-many` and using `on delete cascade` will delete all the child record. So if you delete say author = 1 and then using the on delete cascade it will serve the purpose in `authors_books` but for deleting the books you still need to write custom query. Not sure if it could be done using constraint.